# Invoke and Schedule a GitHub Action workflow from a upstream workflow

Tags: github-actions, cicd

Is there a way to schedule a github action workflow from an upstream workflow?

Expectation:
Once the WorkFlowOne SUCCESS, it will invoke WorkFlowTwo but WorkFlowTwo has to be wait for 1hr to stop/terminate the grid server.

So far I could think of like below, but Is there any other and better way?

**WorkFlowOne.yaml**

```yaml
name: WorkFlowOne
on:
  workflow_dispatch:
  push:
    branches: [ main ]
  pull_request:
    branches: [ main ]

jobs:
  start_grid:
    name: Start Grid
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Get Token
        run: ...
      - name: Start Grid
        run: ./startGrid.sh 
  run_test:
    name: Run Test
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    needs: start_grid
    steps:
      - name: invoke test
        run: |
           sleep 5m 10s
           startTest.sh
```

**WorkFlowTwo.yaml**

```yaml
name: WorkFlowTwo
on:
  workflow_run:
    workflows: [ "WorkFlowOne" ]
    branches: [ main ]
    types: [ completed ]

  workflow_dispatch:
    
jobs:
  terminate_grid:
    name: Terminate Grid
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Stop Grid
        run: | 
            sleep 1h 
            ./stopGrid.sh
```

Comment: If you are on a plan that supports environments, you can [setup an environment protection rule with a timer](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/deployment/targeting-different-environments/using-environments-for-deployment#wait-timer). Not very nice, but at least you're not hogging a runner for an hour :)

Comment: @rethab Agree! with my above approach I'm holding the runner for an hour- Which will be costly after all :) , But I will try your suggestion